# How to Add filters to Twitter4J stream dynamically without starting and stopping stream

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4J to read from the Twitter Stream.
Here is my simple code (there's more but this is the fundamental piece)

```
TwitterStream   twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(authenticate()).getInstance();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
fq = new FilterQuery("bomb");

twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

The authenticate() method establishes a configuration object as per the api. The parameter fq is a FilterQuery object that I put at the class level (of my JavaFX app) in an attempt to be able to modify the reference in a button click event. It doesn't work. I am reading the stream no problem, but a change to the filter query object reference doesn't take.

The problem I'm having is that if I just re-call `twitterStream.filter(...)` again, it actually apparently re-authenticates and then twitter blocks me for doing too many connections from the same app key etc, so I moved the `FilterQuery` reference and hoped that altering that would work; it didn't.

So how can I add keywords to my stream filter without reestablishing the connection, if it's possible?